# How to add color on click event dynamically?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to add color onclick event using three js? Can anyone help? I have the below code:

```
        var pts = [], numPts = 5;
    for ( var i = 0; i < numPts * 2; i ++ ) {
        var l = i % 2 == 1 ? 10 : 20;
        var a = i / numPts * Math.PI;
        pts.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( Math.cos( a ) * l, Math.sin( a ) * l ) );
    }

    var shape = new THREE.Shape( pts );
    var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
    var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x66CC00, wireframe: false } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material2 );
    scene.add( mesh );
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to assign a new color in the `color` property of the material of the mesh in your `onclick` handler. For example, to make it red just add the following lines in your `onclick` handler -

```
mesh.material.color = new THREE.Color(0xff0000);
mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

**Update:**

Declare the variable `mesh` in global space then initiate it in the function like this -

```
var mesh;

function init() {

var pts = [], numPts = 5;
            for ( var i = 0; i < numPts * 2; i ++ ) {
                var l = i % 2 == 1 ? 10 : 20;
                var a = i / numPts * Math.PI;
                pts.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( Math.cos( a ) * l, Math.sin( a ) * l ) );
            }

            var shape = new THREE.Shape( pts );
            var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
            var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x66CC00, wireframe: false } );
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material2 );
            scene.add( mesh );
}
```

Comment: i tried this one also, The below error was occurred:     ReferenceError: mesh is not defined

Comment: you have any other example for color change dynamically. if you have please share it.

Comment: You are probably declaring the `mesh` variable in a function. You need to declare the variable(`mesh`) in global space outside of any function. Then you can initiate it in the function.

Comment: Yes, Its works, How to apply front and back color same time ? can you help?

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov (1) Do not instantiate a new `Color`. Use `mesh.material.color.setHex( 0xff0000 ).` (2) Do not set the `needsUpdate` flag. That unnecessarily recomplies the shader.